Is there a way to create an instance of USBMSD based on a file in the flash?
I'm new to C++ and I'm having a problem programming my Raspberry Pi Pico. I want to be able to create files in the flash memory from Windows by having it show up as a mass storage device. Creating an instance of USBMSD makes it show up in Windows immediately. The problem is, that I want to read a file from the flash memory and then decide if the flash should come up as a mass storage device.
The USBMSD library that I'm using to mount the flash as a mass storage device comes with the RP2040 Mbed OS board in the Arduino IDE.
I've created a function that creates an instance of USBMSD, but it doesn't show up in Windows.
